# Rails adding data to tables upon creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables User (Devise) and Phones

I would like for it when the user signs up threw registrations done with devise, the user_id and the type of phone is loaded into the Phones table

But I am not sure how to do this. I have linked the User with Phones with

> User.rb

```
has_many :phones
```

> Phones.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

> db (schema)

```
 t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_phones_on_user_id"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check [*`accepts_nested_attributes_for`*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) with [*`fields_for`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

Answer (score 4):

you can run an [`after_create`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create) callback on `User` model

```
after_create :assign_phone

private

def assign_phone
  phone = phones.new
  # assign required values
  phone.save
end
```

As mentioned in the comments, `phone.save` will silently return `false` if there's an error, using `!(bang)` will raise and error another solution is checking if it is saved or not and then perform task that you want..

```
def assign_phone
  phone = phones.new
  # assign required values
  if phone.save
    #on successfull save
  else
    #on failure
  end
end
```

Comment: `phone.save` silently ignores any error that could happen with `phones`, that is an awful advice. One should at least use `phone.save!` there.

Comment: I think `assign_phone` should use `self.build_phones` as relationship is not developing between user and phone?

Comment: @mudasobwa I agree, but since I wanted to provide basic structure, I ignored that, thanks though, I will update.

Comment: @SulmanBaig the relationship is being created, `self` is implied and redundant so no need to use it there, as I am in the model itself with the `user`'s instance. i.e. `self.phones.new` == `phones.new`

Answer (score 0):

in user.rb

```
after_create :assign_phone

def assign_phone
  phone = self.phones.build
  phone.save
end
```

This way you will not be able to add type of phone. However, if you want to save type as well then you have to override "create" method of devise/registrations_controller.rb